# Determing if a point is inside a rectangular prism

Tags: 3d

In a 3d world I have the coordinates of the 8 corners of the rectangular prism and I have the coordinates of a point. How would I determine if the point is inside the space that is covered by the rectangular prism?

tried doing min_x < point x < max_x for x y and z but obviously it wont work...